# Don't allow user to use their dupehammer to reopen their own question

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-reopen, dupehammer

There was recently a question on Stack Overflow that was a duplicate of a previous question. I voted to close as dupe, and as I have dupehammer privileges in a relevant tag, it was closed immediately. The OP then used *his* dupehammer to reopen it.

It seems to me that you shouldn't be able to reopen your *own* question with a dupehammer.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you (as a gold tag badge holder) are *more* qualified to unilaterally decide that the question should be closed, than the OP (as a gold tag badge holder) is to unilaterally decide that the question should be reopened. Why *shouldn't* the OP get to reopen the question?

Comment: @ff524 Because the user has a personal interest in it. Someone else can make a more objective decision.

Answer (score 10):

Why not? What harm can be done?

The gold dupe hammer can work only one single time to each direction.

If the question is really a duplicate, other users can still close it again and the OP won't be able to fight it anymore.

Users with enough experience on the site are trusted to use their power wisely, same way as moderators, so in my opinion should not be blocked when it comes to their own questions/answers.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but people's wisdom frequently goes out the window when dealing with something of their own. It's just a normal human failing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would like to believe that's not always true. For example, if someone will close a question of mine I'll take a really good look before voting to reopen (with or without hammer), and if really a duplicate most likely I'll just thank the one who closed with a comment.

Comment: I'd *like to*, too. But sadly... :-)

Comment: So like Patrick said, in case it happens more than once with same user, you can always flag and moderator can warn the user, since it's indeed abuse of power.

Answer (score 9):

I disagree. The dupe-hammer is a special privilege for trusted users that are experts in a certain tag. If a question of such user gets closed as duplicate and OP edits his question to clarify it is not a duplicate, than he should be able to reopen it.

If a user misused his privilege, like it seems in this case, proper action should be taken, maybe by a moderator.

Comment: *"...and OP edits his question to clarify..."* Reopening the question with the dupehammer doesn't require any edit first.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to show that not every use of the dupehammer on reopening is malicious. That case is a very valid case to use it.